# 404 error when attempting a REST GET call to a controller in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat

I'm attempting to make a REST call to a local Tomcat9 server using Spring. My controller is as follows.

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path="/hello-world")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt the REST requesting using the url, `http://localhost:8080/hello-world`, I receive the following 404 error:

```
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

How can I resolve this? I'm trying to gain more practice with Spring.

[image: screenshot of workspace]

EDIT: I resolved the issue. I stopped the Tomcat server and ran RestfulWebServicesApplication as a Java application.

Comment: You most probably didn't deploy this app as the root application. So you need to prepend its context path which, I guess, is /restful-web-services: `http://localhost:8080/restful-web-services/hello-world`

Comment: @JBNizet, I tried that. It still threw the same error.

Comment: could you share the application.properties file

Comment: @PrakashAyappan, never mind. I fixed it.